# Android Change Touch Screen Orientation ONLY

Tags: android, touch, orientation

I am trying to create a custom device with Android and I have the device working well with at this point (looks good visually & with touch). The issue I am having is that the touchscreen does not always agree with the screen orientation. Here is the problem:

The device is set up as a tablet, and will be affixed to a table. But I want to make one version that can be used as a left-hand unit (with a small control section on the left) or a right-hand unit and have the splashscreen change with the unit orientation. My LCD allows me to flip it 180 degrees using a switch, and I can read in that signal on my processor. The problem is that when I flip the screen with the switch, the touch sensor does not come with. Where would I change this configuration? I have access to the AOSP source code, and can build custom ROMS, so that is not an issue.

Now you may also respond that I could use the accellerometer, but the issue with that is that I would see a couple of seconds of the screen being upside-down, and then the reorientation. I need it to boot up as flawlessly in the correct orientation as possible.

What I need: A place in the source code or a setting that I can change in Android that would let me change the touch screen orientation without changing the screen orientation.

Thank you for your help!